# postgresql replace table without losing dependancies

Tags: postgresql, alter-table, table, replace

i want to replace an existing table with a new one, without losing foreign keys or inheritance relations. But I feel lazy to alter it to make it look like the new one. Is there a way to replace the table without doing all the hard job? Like a **CREATE OR REPLACE** statement in **SQLITE** or by tweaking the table name in **pg_class** table?

```
CREATE TABLE a (
  id serial NOT NULL,
  -- a bunch of other columns
  CONSTRAINT a_pk PRIMARY KEY(a)
);

CREATE TABLE b (
  id serial NOT NULL,
  a_id bigint refernces a(id)
);

--REPLACE a with a new table without violating b FOREIGN KEY relations(somehow)
CREATE OR REPLACE a( 
  id serial NOT NULL,
  -- a bunch of new columns
  CONSTRAINT a_pk PRIMARY KEY(a)
);
```

Comment: What's wrong with using `ALTER TABLE`?

Comment: It's not wrong, it's just a lot when you have written a replacement for a bunch of tables, and i know that some other rdb's have this feature @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: I have never seen a `create or replace table` in any other DBMS (Oracle, SQL Server, DB2, Firebird, HSQLDB, ....)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name SQLite has it

Comment: @Benedictus How does that work? Magic? If you `create or replace` a table with a `blah varchar(8)` column and the replacement has a `blah integer` column, what happens? Does it assume that since they're the same name you want to try to coerce the data?

Comment: the data does not matter, asume there's no data, only column thad doesn't change is the one with private key @CraigRinger . Magic? Very funny..

Comment: Postgres has DROP TABLE T IF EXISTS which is much the same.

Answer (score 3):

1. Disable any FKs pointing to the table
2. Create table SAVE as SELECT * FROM A
3. Truncate table A
4. Begin to create a script with the following

> ```
> with xfer as (select cast ('a' as text) as targ_tab, cast ('b' as text) as from_tab)
> select xfer.*, tabs.table_name as targ_table_name, cols.table_name as from_table_name,
>   'alter table ' || tabs.table_name || ' add (' ||
>   coalesce(cols.column_name, '') || ' ' || coalesce (cols.data_type, '')
>   ||  
>       case when data_type = 'numeric' and coalesce (cols.numeric_precision,
>           cols.numeric_scale) is not null then
>           '(' || coalesce ('' || cols.numeric_precision, '*') || ', ' ||
>           coalesce (cols.numeric_scale, 0) || ')'
>       else ''
>       end
>   || ')' 
>   as synt
> from xfer join
>   information_schema.tables tabs on (xfer.targ_tab = tabs.table_name) 
>   join
>   information_schema.columns cols on (xfer.from_tab = cols.table_name)
> where not exists (
> select 1
> from information_schema.columns targcols
> where targcols.table_name = xfer.targ_tab
> and targcols.column_name = cols.column_name
> )
> order by ordinal_position
> ```

5. Repopulate with INSERT/SELECT
6. Re-enable foreign keys